# Why is this list being duplicated when parsing JSON?

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON file that I'm using to populate a select list. Each of the entries in the JSON file is being duplicated in the select list. What is wrong, this seems like it should work:

```
$.each(data, function(index, item){
  items.push('<option value="'+item.partnerID +'">'+item.pName+'</option>');
  $('#platform').append( items.join('') );
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ky6wzLs9/1/)

Comment: Perks or working late without food or coffee... I've been there, I am there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're joining and append the generated list *inside* the loop, after each item is added to it.

That means for every item, you're building the list and appending it to the select up to the current item you're iterating over. Given inputs like `[A, B, C, D]`, you'll wind up with `[A, AB, ABC, ABCD]`.

You need to move the final join outside the loop, so you're only appending `<option>`s to your `<select>` *once* after they've all been built.

```
$.each(data, function(index, item){
  items.push('<option value="'+item.partnerID +'">'+item.pName+'</option>');
});
$('#platform').append( items.join('') );
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I overlooked that.

Answer (score 2):

Put this outside the loop

`$('#platform').append( items.join('') );`

It should be like this

```
$.each(data, function(index, item){
  items.push('<option value="'+item.partnerID +'">'+item.pName+'</option>');
});
$('#platform').append( items.join('') );
```

Here is your updated [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/ky6wzLs9/6/)